# f2py module-level character variable length via parameter from other module

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Consider the following Fortran modules:

`input.f95`

```
module input

  integer, parameter :: identifier_max_length = 8

end module input
```

`utils.f95`

```
module utilities
 use input, only: identifier_max_length

 integer(kind=identifier_max_length) :: ix             ! works !
 character(len=identifier_max_length) :: output_dir    ! DOES NOT work !

contains

 subroutine test
   character(len=identifier_max_length) :: output_dir  ! works !
   write(*, *) ix, output_dir
 end subroutine
end module
```

To compile it with f2py, I first compile `input.f95` as a shared lib:

```
gfortran -shared -O2 -o libinput.so -fPIC input.f95
```

and then `utils.f95` to a python module:

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c --fcompiler=gfortran -L. -I. -linput -m utils utils.f95
```

The character length definition for the module-level variable `output_dir` returns an error `use of undeclared identifier 'identifier_max_length'` while the integer definition with the variable works. Oddly enough the same character definition at subroutine level actually works fine. I dug into the [`numpy.f2py.capi_maps.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/f2py/capi_maps.py) code where the type mapping and kind conversion takes place and it looks like variables in character lengths are not taken care of like they are for the kind parameter.

Defining the `identifier_max_length` parameter in the same utils module also solves the problem, but this is not an option in my code base.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Is there a way to convert length statements via the `.f2py_f2cmap` or can I make the C code aware of the `input:identifier_max_length` variable?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour].  I think f2py's support for module constants is incomplete but I am not sure in which exact places.